# Reading connection string from Sharepoint Web.Config

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, database-connection

What is the proper way of accessing database connections string stored in a SharePoint Web.Config? The following is my entry in the web.config.

```
<add name="TestConnection"  connectionString="Server=DEV00012012;Database=Customer;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
```

Appreciate any help you could extend to me regards.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined your connection string in the appSettings tag like:

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="TestConnection" value="" />
  </appSettings>
```

then use the following code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestConnection"].ToString().
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9cff3d9-55a7-4c9e-a94d-2a7408f859f7/how-to-read-connection-string-from-webconfig?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: Hi Waqas,  thank you again for the quick response. I'll try your advice and will let you know how it works out. Regards.

Comment: please marked it as answer n upvote so that community get benifits